# Install MonoDevelop on CentOS 5.5

Tags: installation, centos, monodevelop

i am trying to install MonoDevelop 2.4 in CentOS 5.5 using yum, but unable to install and configure to develop .Net Applications in Linux.

i have tried installing it in Fedora 13, Monodevelop installed successfully using yum, but not in CentOS 5.5.

Kindly please help me in figuring out how to install MonoDevelop in CentOS 5.5.

Looking for favorable replies.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there is no package for CentOS yet, you may build/install from source code directly.

http://monodevelop.com/Download

Comment: i thought that there is any custom rpm, some file available which will install monodevelop in centos easily rather than building it from source code.

Answer (score 0):

Dag Wieers repository has the monodevelop stuff..  I confirmed on one of my Centos boxes by typing the following at the command line:

```
yum search mono
```

If you need to install the DAG repo here is a link to the how-to:

http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/FAQ.php#B